# Map multiple foreign keys to same primary key in Springboot jpa

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, database-design, spring-data-jpa, relationship

I am working on a simple todos application in springboot. I am using MySQL.
I have two entity classes : a. Users b. Todos
Now I want to map the tables so that I can store the details of :

1. Which user created the todo item
2. Which user completed the item
3. Which user deleted the item

User entity has primary key "id" coulmn and a unqiue, not null column "publicUserId".

What is the most the suitable way to design both tables ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the dreaded "150" error, do one of the following

- Create the table `Users` *first* so that the FK declarations will work.  (As shown by the example below.)
- Use `ALTER` to add the FKs *after both* tables are `CREATEd`.

Sample Creates:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    publicUserId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(publicUserId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ToDos (
    -- ...
    created_by   MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    completed_by MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED     NULL,
    deleted_by   MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED     NULL,
    -- ...
    FOREIGN KEY(created_by)   REFERENCES Users(publicUserId),
    FOREIGN KEY(completed_by) REFERENCES Users(publicUserId),
    FOREIGN KEY(deleted_by)   REFERENCES Users(publicUserId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

- `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` allows for 16M "users" and takes 3 bytes; adjust accordingly.
- I assume a ToDo will always have a `created_by`, hence `NOT NULL`, but the other two user ids start out as `NULL`.
- A schema will work fine without any FKs.  The only thing you lose is dynamic consistency checking in certain situations.  That is, you *could* build your app without any FKs.
- As for how to do the equivalent in the framework that you are using,...  Sorry, but my brain has run out of room to learn the same thing in two different languages.

Comment: I'll try to find some framework related solution and if couldn't, I'll go with this one. Thanks for your response